# Open directory from server using Java on local machine

Tags: java, swing

I made an Java application, that on some point opens a local directory or file. The program is located on a server (executed by an other desktop). When an existing folder/file is opened by the app (that is located on the server, and accesed remotely), no screen pops up. If i run the Java program on my desktop, the opening of the of the local folder/file works fine.

I think that the problem is that, when i call the "open folder/file function" i acces the desktop of the server. But the window needs to be openend by the "calling" pc. So i need to specify that the desktop of the calling computer should be used.

How can i accomplish this?

Here is the function that i use to open a folder/file:

```
try {
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(path));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the application is remotely accesed something like this: \\10.0.0.1\Java\App.jar

Comment: Won't this leads to security breach ? I doubt, `Java` Security allows accessing system resources, without the consent of the `User` concern. Though again, I am not an expert on Security related material, just a thought I presented :-)

Comment: If you are running a java application via a JAR hosted on an SMB share, the application is running in a local JRE even if the JAR file is remote. In order to reasonably answer this you'd have to tell us what the return value for `isDesktopSupported()` is or if you are getting an exception what that exception is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you access the Java application like this: \10.0.0.1\Java\App.jar you are still running the application from the local machine.
In order for it to be run on the server you would have a Java process running on that server and then on the local machine you would have another Java application that is the client for the server application.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using Windows and your Server is mounted with an SMB share. Try to mount the remote server directory to a local drive letter like R:, this should solve access problems.

Comment: I just tried this, now the app does not function at all. It won't preform any actions when i push buttons on the GUI...